# Selenium - Use InternetExplorerOptions() when initializing RemoteWebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-iedriver

I am trying to get IE to start each session clean when intializing a remote driver via the Selenium grid.  This

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = null;
caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://10.10.22.126:5555/wd/hub"), caps);
```

is not working, IE is starting each new test with the cookies from the previous test, which causes issues.  I am trying to implement this

```
InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions()
                .destructivelyEnsureCleanSession();
```

As dictated [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/ie/InternetExplorerOptions.html), but I can't figure out how to use this as a remote driver instead of locally.  Thanks!

Comment: does setting this `ieOptions` as a capability not work?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the option as a capability in somewhat this manner:

```
InternetExplorerOptions ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions()
         .destructivelyEnsureCleanSession();
capabilities.setCapability("se:ieOptions", ieOptions);
```

The `InternetExplorerOptions` class defines the constant for this capability as:

```
private final static String IE_OPTIONS = "se:ieOptions";
```

Comment: Interesting.  Can you tell me what that is doing?

Comment: @kroe761 That would set the option as one of your driver's capability.

Comment: Well, yeah, but i was wondering about `"se:ieOptions"` more than anything.  I've never ran across that.

Comment: @kroe761 You can find it inside the InternetExplorerOptions class.